# Should I close os.File before calling os.removeAll?

Tags: go, file-io

so if I've created a temp file in temp directory, used it and now I need to remove it(or them), should I call first file.Close() and then os.RemoveAll, or if I call os.RemoveAll it is unnecessary to close files? Is then file descriptor freed?

Comment: "used it [the temp file]" is almost impossible without `Close`ing it  properly. Close exists to be called (not so much for RemoveAll which might or not might work on the OS) but to finish the file.

Comment: `Close()` should be finally called (after or before `RemoveAll()`), otherwise you will block some system resources.

On Windows you must close everything before `RemoveAll()`, otherwise `RemoveAll()` will fail.

But

Comment: Ok, thank you, so the order of calling `RemoveAll` and `Close()` is not important? It is not that I need to call it in reverse order, but just to be sure, that order is not really important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux removing a file causes its name to be removed from the file system but the block of storage will remain on disk while you still have an open file descriptor and removed only once that file descriptor (and any other file descriptors opened on that file) is closed. See https://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink

In go, the open file descriptor will not be closed just because you call `os.RemoveAll()` on a directory that contains the file.

I believe microsoft windows works differently: I think you will get an error when you try to remove a file that's currently being written to. That could be wrong, I'm no expert on Windows. But again, the open file descriptor will not be closed automatically.